# Creating onclick for elements with parameter values that are not in current scope

Tags: javascript, html

I am looking to create a list of elements that will essentially be listed in a div and have onclicks applied to them. I am successfully able to assign the function I wish to use on the onclick, however I am having trouble with passing parametets to the function I have outlined.

To make things more complex, I do not have the variables that will be passed to the function available where I am setting the function that the onclick will point to. I do however know what the names of the variables will be when I am determining what variables are going to be passed.

To help demonstrate the situation, I have created a small sample that strictly covers my requirements. In the sample I am creating the elements to appear on the page with the onclicks in the variable 'list'. Within list I have the label that will appear, the function that will be called when I click, and another variable that contains the variables that will be passed to the function. For this example I am just using one function that will be called, but in production I will have a large variety of different functions that could be called.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>   
     <div id="testDiv">

     </div>

     <script>

         var list = [];
         list.push({label: "Hello", func: updateValue, params: "Dog"});
         list.push({label: "Goodbye", func: updateValue, params: "Rubber"}); 

         //values is defined in a later function where this element will be created       
         list.push({label: "Another", func: updateValue, params: values[0]});
         aFunction();

         function aFunction()
         {
             var values = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];
             var containerDiv = document.getElementById("testDiv");

             for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i += 1) 
             {
                 addOptionInUI(containerDiv, list[i]);
             }
         }

         function addOptionInUI(parentContainer, item)
         {
             var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
             newDiv.onclick = item.func;
             newDiv.innerHTML = '<span>' + item.label + '</span>';

             parentContainer.appendChild(newDiv);
         }

         function updateValue(aVariable, maybeAnother)
         {
             var result = "Variable - " + aVariable;

             if(maybeAnother != undefined)
                 result += ", " + maybeAnother + " was also added";

             alert(result);
         }

     </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The sample above may not be set up correctly to do what I require. For instance instead of having the params and func properties separately, I may need to have the entire function to be called represented as a string and sort it out from there, but I'm not sure how that would look.

Unfortunately I am unaware of the correct terminology to use given my requirements, so it made finding a solution difficult.

Additionally, if this is something that simply shouldn't/can't be done, fair cop. Any help would be greatly appreciated, cheers in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated your code with the following:

- Updated the items in your list to include a callback function with the parameters, instead of passing parameter and the method separately. [Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function)
- In the `updateValue` method, I have remove the parameter definitions, and now is instead using arguments property, which will contains all the arguments passed. [Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments)

I am assuming that the value of the variables are not changing, and if they are changing then I guess you will have to either create a class with those data members and functions, or declare the variables globally which might be a bad practice depending on what you are doing exactly.

I have a strong feeling that the problem you are trying to solve is more complex than the solution below helps with, but I hope it solves some of the problems you are facing.

I hope the following helps:

```js
var list = [];
   // Updating the func to be a callback function with the parameters you need to pass
   // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function
   list.push({label: "One parameter", func: () => updateValue("Dog") });
   list.push({label: "Two parameter", func: () => updateValue("Dog", "Rubber") });
   list.push({label: "No parameter", func: () => updateValue() });

   aFunction();

   function aFunction()
   {
       var values = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];
       var containerDiv = document.getElementById("testDiv");

       for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i += 1) 
       {
           addOptionInUI(containerDiv, list[i]);
       }
   }

   function addOptionInUI(parentContainer, item)
   {
       var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
       newDiv.onclick = item.func;
       newDiv.innerHTML = '<span>' + item.label + '</span>';

       parentContainer.appendChild(newDiv);
   }

  // Dont define any parameters here, and use the arguments property to access them
  // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments
   function updateValue() {
      var result = "";
      for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
          result += (arguments[i] + ", ");
      }
      alert(result);
   }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>   
     <div id="testDiv">
     </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Alternative approach using a class. This example mutates data, and simulates loading data from database:

```js
class CallbacksAndData {
  constructor(value0, value1, dog) {
    this.values = [value0, value1];
    this.dog = [dog];
  }

  incrementIndex0 = () => {
    this.values[0]++;
    alert(this.values[0]);
  }
  
  decrementIndex1 = () =>  {
    this.values[1]--;
    alert(this.values[1]);
  }
  
  getSum = () =>  {
    if (this.values[1] < 0) {
        alert(`${this.values.join('')} = ${this.values[0] + this.values[1]}`);
    } else {
        alert(`${this.values.join('+')} = ${this.values[0] + this.values[1]}`);
    }
  }

  callbackDog = () =>  {
      alert(this.dog);
  }
}

var callbacks = new CallbacksAndData(1, 2, "pup");
var list = [];
list.push({label: "incrementIndex0", func: callbacks.incrementIndex0 });
list.push({label: "decrementIndex1", func: callbacks.decrementIndex1 });
list.push({label: "getSum", func: callbacks.getSum });
list.push({label: "callbackDog", func: callbacks.callbackDog });

aFunction();

function aFunction() {
  var values = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];
  var containerDiv = document.getElementById("testDiv");

  for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i += 1) {
    addOptionInUI(containerDiv, list[i]);
  }
}

function addOptionInUI(parentContainer, item) {
  var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
  newDiv.onclick = item.func;
  newDiv.innerHTML = '<span>' + item.label + '</span>';

  parentContainer.appendChild(newDiv);
}

function loadFromDatabase() {
    callbacks.values = [20, 30];
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>   
     <div id="testDiv">

     </div>
     <button id="testDiv" onClick="loadFromDatabase()">
       Load from Database
     </button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is a really great step in the right direction, thank you very much! I realise I wasn't clear in my question though, so I will update that. Essentially one of those callbacks would look like: __func: () => updateValue(values[0])__ where values is defined in a later function as presented in my example. Once I can do that, I am good to go! 

Thanks again, this is defintiely helpful to know!

Comment: I have added another approach which works with changing data. Hope it helps!

Comment: The only issue with the new version is that it is not pointing to values that are inside the __values__ array in aFunction(). What I would need is for some way for the __list__ variable with the callbacks to point towards values within that __values__ array. I know it sounds strange, but the situation is that that values array in my ues case is actually an object that I get from a database, and won't know the details of until I get into the function. Before then however, I will have the onclicks set up because I know the functionality and type of data to expect.

Comment: Once you retrieve the value from the database, you can make it a member of `CallbacksAndData` object. Its just encapsulating the data and the methods together in one class, classic OOPS at play.

Comment: I think you are on to something there! I'll test it out and let you know how I go. Thanks a tonne, really appreciate the advice so far!

Comment: I made edit to the "Alternative approach", and added a "Load from Database" button. Give that a shot! It will sets the list to [20, 30]